# CNContact Example of a Fetch and import of a Contact into App

Tags: ios, xcode, cncontact, cncontactstore, cncontactviewcontroller

I have been using `ABPeople` Picker to show Contacts and then import the selected contact into my app.

Need to migrate to `CNContact` as `AB` has become unreliable.

I have found some examples but they're all in Swift.  Specifically, need ObjectiveC help with `CNContactPickerViewController`.

Current code looks like this:

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
{
    CFTypeRef generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    if (generalCFObject) {
        self.first = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

        NSLog (@"First Name %@",first);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by the following code :

```
-(void)selectContactData {

    CNContactPickerViewController * picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.displayedPropertyKeys = (NSArray *)CNContactGivenNameKey;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSString *test = contact.givenName;
    NSLog(@"%@",test);

}
```

The displayed property keys can be anything like `CNContactEmailAddressesKey` for email. etc

for selecting multiple contacts use `contactPicker:didSelectContacts:`
 instead of `contactPicker:didSelectContact:` in the above code